# Mongoengine and Pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, django-rest-framework, pymongo, mongoengine, djongo

Can I use mongoengine or djongo for ODM and pymongo for interaction with the db?

I've read these two about something related to my question:

[Insert data by pymongo using mongoengine ORM in pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334056/insert-data-by-pymongo-using-mongoengine-orm-in-pyramid)

[Use MongoEngine and PyMongo together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068558/use-mongoengine-and-pymongo-together)

But, I couldn't find what I'm looking for (I guess).
So here's what I'm trying to find:

¿Does this practice affect the performance of my application?
¿How well recommended is it?

So, if it is recommended, and everything is right, ¿Do I need to put an extra layer of security or something?, because, I want to build an API using the serializations for models that django-rest-framework-mongoengine offers, and then do what I have to do in the view of the API endpoint.

It could be djongo or something like it, what I want is just an ODM for serializing, define a structure for the API and so on, use pymongo for queries, cause according to what I've been reading, mongoengine could make slower the interaction with the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "ORM" does not apply to MongoDB since MongoDB is non-relational. The proper term is "ODM" - object-document mapper.

Generally, a MongoDB ODM is built on top of a MongoDB driver. The functionalities of the ODM and the driver are complementary - the driver provides low-level database access and the ODM provides high-level features like schema, associations, callbacks.

If you want to use the high-level features, it makes sense to use an ODM. If you don't need any of those features and just want to perform basic CRUD operations, using a driver directly is more efficient. Some applications use both of these strategies depending on the operation that needs to be performed.

Comment: I understand, I got wrong with that term, but it is still not clear for me, should I use it or not?, I mean, potentially, there could be more than CRUD operations, also, I'm having some trouble understanding the drf request handling, because I'm not sure if I could use mongod within an API that could have thousands of requests, and well, I'm not sure if will ended up  working with multi threading or something like that

Comment: I suggest building a working application using either option first. Chances are your first application will be just fine either way.